# Processing GenArt | How to save Shape as GIF

Tags: python, processing, gif, generative-art

Goal: export this output as a GIF.

This is working code, using **[Processing](https://processing.org/)** and Python.

This actually runs forever, how do I stop it after a while so as I can save as GIF?

```py
import random
radius = 0

def setup():
    global displayWidth, displayHeight, radius
    size(displayWidth, displayHeight)
    background(0)
    noFill()
    stroke(255, 25)
    radius = height / 2
    
def draw():
    global radius
    center_x = width / 2
    center_y = height / 2
    
    beginShape()
    for i in range(360):
        _noise = noise(i * 0.02, float(frameCount) / 50)
        x = center_x + radius * cos(radians(i)) * _noise
        y = center_y + radius * sin(radians(i)) * _noise
        curveVertex(x, y)
        
        if radius == 0:
            stroke(225, 0, 0, 10)
        if radius == 100:
            stroke(0, 225, 0, 25)
        if radius == 200:
            stroke (0, 0, 225, 25)

    endShape(CLOSE)
    
    radius -= 1
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I should add to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. GIFs are not supported in [processing](https://processing.org/). However you can use [`saveFrame()`](https://processing.org/reference/saveFrame_.html) to saves a numbered sequence of images. Just call `saveFrame()` at the end of `draw`. There are numerous tools that can create a GIF from a list of images.